# How to "secure" php pages with session_start();?

Tags: php, security, session, redirect, cookies

I am making a "members" page within a website, where "members" can access this page with a predetermined username and password that already exists. I made a php file that reads the "username" and "passwrod" variables and if the values are correct, the user is sent to this "members.php" page and if not it is sent to another page. My question is: How can I make the "members.php" page only available to the users that already submitted the correct username and password, and if the user is not in the "session" to be redirected to the page with the access form.

```
    <?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username == 'correctusername' AND $password == 'correctpassword')
{

    header("location:members.php");

}
else {

    header("location:wrong.php");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($username == 'correctusername' AND $password == 'correctpassword')
    {
    //apart from session you can use this urlencode () and get on members page with urldecode
        header("location:members.php?foo='urlencode($username)'");

    }
    else {

        header("location:wrong.php?foo='urlencode($username)'");
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting all the code for the members.php page within a

```
if (isset($_SESSION)){ 
  //all code for the page goes here
}else{
// redirect to other page
}
```

You can also have a function for session which will set a boolean value say $member = true for a member depending on userName and password , then you can check for

```
if(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION['member']{
  //all code for the page for view by members only goes here
}else{
  redirect to another page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like?:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && ($_SESSION['loggedIn']=='true')){
//the session variable is already set for this user so not needed to check again
header("location:members.php");
exit;
}
else if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
//if the user is submitting for the first time, check.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($username == 'correctusername' AND $password == 'correctpassword')
  {
    //setting session so on next visit to this page, they are 
    //automatically redirected
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 'true';
    header("location:members.php");
    exit;

  }
  else {
    //if posted values are wrong
    header("location:wrong.php");
    exit;
   }
}
else {
//this block evaluates to true if session has not been set and if no
//'username' or 'password' has been posted
}


?>
```